# How to connect Power BI to MS SQL through dataGateway only

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I need to connect to a MS SQL server that is on an amazon AWS virtual machine.

I downloaded and configured the enterprise data gateway and in my Power BI web interface it says connection successful.

But in my Power BI desktop how do I access the MS SQL server using this gateway? I cannot connect directly to this MS SQL server from my desktop

I tried get data and entered the IP which matches the IP I used when I setup the data gateway but it does not work.

How can I connect from Power BI Desktop to my cloud based MS SQL through the gateway then I have no direct access to the MS SQL server from my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand it, the gateway is not a data source from the perspective of Power BI Desktop's Get Data. You need access to the SQL Server. The gateway comes into play for users who will connect from powerbi.com.

Reference:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Connecting-Power-BI-to-On-Premise-data-with-Power-BI-Gateways/ba-p/84797

> When developing reports using an on premise data source and the on-premises gateway, it is necessary to develop the reports in the Power BI Desktop tool.  The Power BI Desktop tool must be used from a machine that has access to the on premise data source.

Comment: Pretty weird but I understand hope that changes in the future